# Validity of a proof of the Fisher Information Data Processing inequality, $I(f(X)) \le I(X)$.

Tags: probability, notation, lebesgue-integral, information-theory

I'm trying to prove that taking a function of a random variable never creates a better estimator (in the terms of [Fisher information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information)) than using the original random variable directly.

I have a proof (below), but I'm worried that I'm abusing the Lebesgue integral notation too much.
I'm worried about operations like introducing an extra $\frac{dP}{dP}$ and breaking these up as if they were fractions.
I'm also unsure if I should write $\frac{d \log P(x)}{d\rho}$ or $\frac{\log dP(x)}{d\rho}$ or even $\frac{d}{d\rho}\log dP(x)$...

I would really appreciate if anybody could check the proof (which is quite trivial, only using a single application of Cauchy Schwarz) and let me know how to make it formal. (Or if it already is?)

**Fisher Information Data Processing Inequality:**

Let $X$ be a random variable with distribution $dP$,
and let $f$ be some channel with distribution $f(x) \sim dQ(q|x)$.
Then
$$
      I(f(X)) \le I(X),
   $$
where $I[X] = E_X\left[\left(\frac{\log dP}{d\rho}\right)^2\right]$ is the Fischer information of $X$.

**Proof:**

Let $dQ$ the marginalized distribution of $f(X)$.
Then
\begin{align}
      I[f(X)]
      &= E_Q\left[\left(\frac{\log dQ}{d\rho}\right)^2\right]
    \\&= E_Q\left[\left(\frac{1}{dQ}\frac{dQ}{d\rho}\right)^2\right]
    \\&= \int_q\frac{1}{dQ(q)}\left(\frac{d Q(q)}{d\rho}\right)^2
    \\&= \int_q\frac{1}{dQ(q)}\left(\frac{d}{d\rho}\int_x dQ(q|x) dP(x)\right)^2
    \\&= \int_q\frac{1}{dQ(q)}\left(\int_x dQ(q|x) \frac{dP(x)}{d\rho}\right)^2
    \\&= \int_q\frac{1}{dQ(q)}\left(\int_x dQ(q|x) \frac{dP(x)}{d\rho} \frac{dP(x)}{dP(x)}\right)^2
    \\&= \int_q\frac{1}{dQ(q)}\left(\int_x dQ(q|x) \frac{\log dP(x)}{d\rho} dP(x)\right)^2
    \\&\le \int_q\frac{1}{dQ(q)}\int_x dQ(q|x) dP(x) \int_x dQ(q|x) \left(\frac{\log dP(x)}{d\rho}\right)^2 dP(x)
    \\&= \int_q\frac{dQ(q)}{dQ(q)} \int_x dQ(q|x) \left(\frac{\log dP(x)}{d\rho}\right)^2 dP(x)
    \\&= \int_q \int_x dQ(q|x) \left(\frac{\log dP(x)}{d\rho}\right)^2 dP(x)
    \\&= \int_x \left(\int_q dQ(q|x)\right) \left(\frac{\log dP(x)}{d\rho}\right)^2 dP(x)
    \\&= \int_x \left(\frac{\log dP(x)}{d\rho}\right)^2 dP(x)
    \\&= E_X\left[\left(\frac{\log dP}{d\rho}\right)^2\right]
    \\&= I(X)
   \end{align}

Comment: Fisher information is defined as
$$I(\rho) = \mathbb{E} \left [ \left ( \dfrac{\partial}{\partial \rho} \log \dfrac{dP}{dx}  \right )^2 \right ],$$
You have forgotten a $\dfrac{1}{dx}$.

Comment: The main idea for the proof is to use the fact that 
$$I(\rho) = \mathbb{E} \left [ \mathbb{E} \left [ \left (\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \rho} \log \dfrac{dP}{dx} \right )^2 \bigg \vert f(X) \right ]  \right ],$$
and the property of $\log$ that $\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b)$.

Comment: Hm, somehow I was thinking about $dP(x)$ as the density function of $X$. But I suppose that goes to show some of my confusion about differentials vs derivatives.

Comment: Would it then be correct to write $\frac{d}{d\rho} \log \frac{dP}{dx} = \frac{d^2P(x)}{dx\, d\rho} \big/ \frac{dP(x)}{dx} = \frac{d^2P(x)}{d\rho\, dP(x)}$? Or maybe I should only have $(x)$ once, so $\frac{d^2P(x)}{d\rho\, dP}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by gandalf, there were indeed some issues with confusing densities, differentials and derivatives.

I believe the version below fixes the issues.

Let $Q$ the distribution of $Y=f(X)$ and $q=\frac{dQ}{dy}$ the density.
Then
$$
   \begin{align}
      I(Y)
      &= E_Y\left[\left(\frac{d}{d\rho}\log q(Y)\right)^2\right]
    \\&= E_Y\left[\left(\frac{1}{q(Y)}\frac{dq(Y)}{d\rho}\right)^2\right]
    \\&= \int_y\left(\frac{1}{q(y)}\frac{dq(y)}{d\rho}\right)^2 dQ(y)
    \\&= \int_y\frac{dQ(y)}{q(y)^2}\left(\frac{dq(y)}{d\rho}\right)^2
    \\&= \int_y\frac{dy}{q(y)}\left(\frac{d}{d\rho}\int_x q(y|x)p(x)dx\right)^2
    \\&= \int_y\frac{dy}{q(y)}\left(\int_x q(y|x) \frac{dp(x)}{d\rho} dx\right)^2
    \\&= \int_y\frac{dy}{q(y)}\left(\int_x q(y|x) \frac{dp(x)}{d\rho} \frac{p(x)}{p(x)}dx\right)^2
    \\&= \int_y\frac{dy}{q(y)}\left(\int_x q(y|x) \frac{d \log p(x)}{d\rho} dP(x)\right)^2
    \\&\le \int_y\frac{dy}{q(y)}\left(\int_x q(y|x) dP(x)\right)\left( \int_x q(y|x) \left(\frac{d \log p(x)}{d\rho}\right)^2 dP(x)\right)
    \\&= \int_y\frac{dy}{q(y)} q(y) \int_x q(y|x) \left(\frac{d \log p(x)}{d\rho}\right)^2 dP(x)
    \\&= \int_y dy \int_x q(y|x) \left(\frac{d \log p(x)}{d\rho}\right)^2 dP(x)
    \\&= \int_x \left(\int_y q(y|x)dy\right) \left(\frac{d \log p(x)}{d\rho}\right)^2 dP(x)
    \\&= \int_x \left(\frac{d \log p(x)}{d\rho}\right)^2 dP(x)
    \\&= E_X\left[\left(\frac{d \log p(X)}{d\rho}\right)^2\right]
    \\&= I(X)
   \end{align}
$$

Where we used that $q(y) = \int_x q(y|x) dP(x)$
and $\int_y q(y|x)dy = 1$.

Comment: On what inner product space are you applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality? To make this rigorous, you need to define what $q(y|x)$ is using [Regular Conditional Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability#:~:text=In%20probability%20theory%2C%20regular%20conditional,measures%20called%20a%20Markov%20kernel.). You also need identify the inner product space and verify that the arguments of the inner product are members of that space.

Comment: I'm using the inner product $\langle q(y|\cdot), \frac{d}{d\rho}\log(p(\cdot))\rangle$ over $P$, or $E_{X\sim P}[q(y|X), \frac{d}{d\rho}\log(p(X))]$. What needs to be identified about it? What conditions do I need to check for $q(y|x)$ to exist? Is it enough that $q$ and $p$ exist and $q >\!> p$?

Comment: $q >> p$ does not have meaning in measure theory unless $q$ and $p$ are measures. I think you mean $Q >> P$, but in this problem, this need not even be true. For example, take $X$ to be Bernoulli, and let $f$ map every real number to $\pi$.  Then $Q$ assigns mass at $\{\pi\} \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ whereas $P$ doesn't.

Comment: How do we know that your formal definition of inner product here doesn't map some pairs to $\pm \infty$? This is why we must identify the space. For example, the $L^2$ space of Lebesgue square integrable functions constitutes an inner product space, whereas absolutely integrable functions do not. So we probably want $q(y|x)$ and $\dfrac{d}{d \rho} \log p(x)$ to be square integrable. But I still don't know what $q(y|x)$ is.